# Understanding Contraction Hierarchies

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, pathfinder

I'm very interested by understanding how Contraction Hierarchies algorithm works. I have found this page : https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/contraction-hierarchies/ and read a lot of stuff. I understood how the algorithm goes and work except for one part. I didn't grasp how the contraction strategy really work. (Important: I'm not fluent in Maths).

In the first example on the page given above, the contraction order is 6→8→3→0→5→7→4→1→2→9 and I can't understand why. The explanations are not clear to me and [the original article](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/schultes/hwy/contract.pdf) contains too much maths in it.

Can someone, please, explain the strategy used to define the contraction order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned on the web page, any order will work, in the sense that the query will find a shortest path. However some orders are much better than others in terms of the time taken to preprocess the graph, and the time taken for shortest-path queries.

One rule of thumb is that the fewer shortcuts you add, the less time you take searching edges during preprocessing and querying. A way to reduce the number of shortcuts is to consider the "edge-difference" of a node: this is the number of shortcuts that would need to be added *if* you contracted that node next, minus the number of edges that would get contracted. It's preferable to contract nodes with a smaller edge-difference earlier. For example by contracting node 6 first you remove three edges and add one shortcut, giving an edge-difference of minus two,  which is pretty good.

Another rule of thumb is that contractions should occur fairly uniformly over the graph, rather than contracting lots of nearby nodes together. This leads to shorter query times as you tend to have fewer upwards edges to traverse before you reach the top. A decent way to keep contractions uniform is to count the number of already contracted neighbours of each node. Again, it's preferable to contract nodes with a smaller number of contracted neighbours earlier.

There are other possible rules of thumb (or "heuristics") that you can use, although most of them are based on the two ideas above. Usually you would use a simple combination of heuristics, for example the edge-difference plus the contracted-neighbour-count. The web page author's code is available on [Github](https://github.com/michaeltandy/contraction-hierarchies/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/me/mjt/ch/GraphContractor.java), and it looks like he firstly prefers to contract nodes with negative edge differences, then those with fewer contracted neighbours, then those with smaller edge-differences. Sometimes there will be nodes with the same preference value, in which case he uses a hash code to determine the order.

There are further subtleties, because one's heuristics change on the remaining nodes as you perform the contractions. It's a bad idea to re-evaluate every node's preference after every contraction,  as this would take ages, but you can approximate such a process by re-evaluating only the neighbours of the node you just contracted. There are other clever tricks like re-evaluating every node at halfway. It's not a definite science, and you should test everything on the input road networks you are working with.